# How to output the symbol @ in Latex

Tags: symbols

I know how to output any symbol but @. Nor does Google know about it. Weird? How do I output @?

Comment: You just hit the `@` key. (If you've got one.) Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Alternative: loading `\usepackage{marvosym}` use the command
`\MVAt` (I think this could be useful for you: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use in your preamble (with @egreg's help):

```
\newcommand\textat{\symbol{64}}
```

Result with `fourier`:

[image]

Comment: Typing `@` is much simpler, isn't it? On the other hand, your definition is wrong. Try `\textat 11` to see why. Mixing primitive syntax with LaTeX syntax is dangerous. It should be either `\chardef\textat=64` or `\newcommand{\textat}{\symbol{64}}`. I believe it is instructive to see what goes wrong in your code.

Comment: You're kidding? I didn't even try

Comment: No joke, try it.

Comment: I've tried it. OK, you win. Lacking a pair of brackaets, or \xspace, but anyway, the space between @ and the following character doesn't vary. But once more, I've learnt something. Thanks!

Comment: @egreg missing space syndrome? Learned that at my own expenses too `:-)`

Comment: @campa That's it! :-)

Comment: @ all. I feel like a total idiot: I never even thought of typing just `@` and wasted half an hour trying all sorts of things. So I now have `\newcommand{\textat}{\symbol{64}}` in my preamble as I was indeed leery of using just @.

Comment: I guess it's mainly because all those `@` in internal LaTeX commands which you can't use in your documents.

Comment: @Bernard But why does @ behave differently from, say, $ or &?

Comment: @ is not special, it is like + or !.

Comment: @schremmer There is *no* special meaning of `@`; its usage in private control sequences is a completely different matter. You just type `@`.

Answer (score 6):

`@`

<sub>No kidding. There's nothing more than this: type `@` and you'll get what you want.</sub>

<sub>However, if you're using a *very* old LaTeX system and still do
`\usepackage{amslatex}` (the package doesn't exist any more in modern distributions), then you have to type `@@`. But note that `amslatex` has been deprecated around 1994.</sub>